# How to execute subcommand in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

Here is my makefile (or at least the relevant part):

```
build-frontend:
    cd frontend; printf '{"tag":"%s"}\n' $(git describe --tags) > VERSION.json
    other-commands
```

When I execute this command from shell it works fine but when I do `make build-frontend`,
it shows me that make executes following command:

```
cd frontend; printf '{"tag":"%s"}\n'  > VERSION.json
```

It looks like the subcommand is executed before `cd frontend`,
but even then it seems weird since in that case it should return version of the deployment script and it returns nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that `$()` is how make does variable subsitution. You need to escape the `$`, like this.

```
build-frontend:
    cd frontend; printf '{"tag":"%s"}\n' $$(git describe --tags) > VERSION.json
    other-commands
```